# How to gobble any buffered STDIN before "pause" in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, stdin

A fair number of our "automate a group of installers" .bat files end with something like:

```
:success
ECHO Success! (as far as I can tell)
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Press any key to reboot...
ECHO.
ECHO.
PAUSE >NUL
shutdown -r
EXIT /b
```

If the prior commands have taken a while, there's a good chance the user has accidentally hit a key well before we reach the `:success` label.  Since `STDIN` seems to be buffered, this will cause the `PAUSE` to be dismissed instantly.

What I'd rather have is something like:

```
GOBBLE_STDIN_SOMEHOW
PAUSE >NUL
shutdown -r
```

How would I "flush" STDIN, consuming anything that was there, but not waiting if there's nothing buffered?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use an alternate method:

```
:success
ECHO Success! (as far as I can tell)
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO Press ENTER key to reboot...
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P DUMMY=
shutdown -r
EXIT /b
```

However, this method fail if the user accidentally hit ENTER...

Comment: Not a bad idea to start, it'll at least limit the stray keys that can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem, as pause seems to work like you want.
It flushes the input buffer before waiting.

Tested with this (I used Vista)

```
@echo off
echo Press now some keys
ping -n 3 localhost > nul
echo Stop pressing
ping -n 3 localhost > nul
echo Now Pause starts (and waits)
pause
```

Comment: Hrm.  Maybe it's something specific about the other installers or `start /wait`...  Will research a bit more.